# Can you close an FTP (ftplib) connection while downloading a file to simulate connection problems in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, pytest, ftplib

I'm writing a test suite in py.test for a class that uses ftplib and such for FTP things.  I need to disrupt the connection I'm using to simulate network problems and cover an exception. Please note, for this project I was required to use a real FTP server instead of mocks, so mocks won't help (I think).

Is there a simple way I can interrupt the port / socket to simulate problems?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FTP` class has the `sock` field.

If you call the [`.close` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) on it, you terminate the FTP session control connection.

Comment: I appreciate your reply and will  check this out at work in the AM.

Comment: Worked great.  Thank you.